# autocomplete using php and html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to do text autocomplete using php and html..
i have tried the below code

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "data") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$sql = "select value from fin";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$dna = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $dna[] = $row['value'];
    }

$jj = array_unique($dna);
print_r(array_values($jj));
?>
```

result is [image: this]

my html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/
            themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4
         /jquery-ui.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="vinform" method="get"> <input type="text" name="editor" autocomplete="on"> <input type="submit" value="Show" id="display"> </form>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#div1').autocomplete({
            source: "auto.php"
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

it doesn't show the words from mysql when i type some word in the text field ..i have to show the related words from mysql based on the text field input,when i type a character in the text field..can anyone help me to solve the issue in my code?

tried with  Ajax

```
              var se = null;

          $(function () {
          var minlength = 1;

       $("#editor").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
    value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length >= minlength ) {
        if (se != null) 
            se.abort();
        se = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "auto.php",
            data: value,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(msg){

                if (value==$(that).val()) {

                }
                   }
                });
               }
             });
          });
```

php

```
                    <?php

                if(isset($_GET['editor']))
                {
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin321","data");       

                if (mysqli_connect_errno())                
                  {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                  }
                  $name=$_GET['editor'];
        $sql = "select value from fin where value LIKE '%".$name."'";
          $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or 
           die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

            $dna = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $dna[] = $row['value'];
            }
            $jj=array_unique($dna);
             print_r ( $jj);

                }
        ?>
```

no autocomplete action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With option 1 (Jquery UI autocomplete) and try something like that

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "data") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$sql = "select value from fin";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$dna = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $dna[] = $row['value'];
    }

echo json_encode($dna);
?>
```

Jquery UI [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) state about source option

> String: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

Comment: thanks for your reply...i tried  -  http://pastebin.com/M9We1Lrt    ,but there is no autocomplete action

Comment: If the answer satisfy you, can you mark it as the answer of the question

Comment: The format returns from pastebin will not work. Do it like I write

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX and Jquery..in html code call the function on keyup event and send data using ajax request after that get data from database using LIKE query and display it..

Comment: tried with ajax and updated in the question,no autocomplete action

Answer (score 0):

in input add id="editor"

```
<input type="text" id="editor" name="editor" autocomplete="on">
```